# Shabbat Blessings Question

Tags: shabbat, blessing, kiddush

My family is Christian but we are trying to observe Shabbat following the Jewish traditions.

I am struggling to get an understanding of exactly how this is done.

I know that you have the Kiddush, Blessing of the bread & wine, blessing of the children and lighting of the candles.

If anyone is willing, could you please share how your family does it - I'd really appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mi Yodeya. According to Jewish law, non-Jews are not allowed to observe Shabbat, so Jewish members here can't assist you with practical explanations on the topic.

Comment: If you had a non-jewish guest at your house on a Friday night, would they not be allowed a seat at the table?

Comment: They would, but a seat at the table is not the same as observing the whole day.

Comment: @Harel13 - I'm exclusively talking about the Friday night dinner traditions/blessings. If you're unable to give me any info on that, I completely understand.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/253218/jewish/Friday-Night-Wizard.htm and/or https://aish.com/shabbat/shabbat-how-to/

Comment: Please do not appropriate our practices. It is offensive. There is a reason why your family has no clue about how to engage such practices. It is because it is not their inheritance. Part of the Kiddush states "and with love and good will You have given us Your holy Sabbath as an inheritance." You reciting those words would be a lie, as it was not given to you.

Comment: The links that @DannySchoemann provided will give you the order of things, but Deuteronomy is correct that the wording of the respective blessings wouldn't work for you. You'd probably have to recast them as, for example, "Blessed is the L-rd, G-d of the Jewish people, King of the universe, who commanded the Jewish people to...". Best, though, might be to get in touch with a Noachide organization to guide you further.

Comment: It is actually forbidden for non Jews to follow the laws of the Sabbat. There are some nonJews known as Noachides who follow certain laws and customs. However, it is definitely forbidden for Christians to attempt to do so as the Christian beliefs contradict the Jewish beliefs.

Comment: Non Jews are not allowed to observe the sabbath. There are other commandments you may observe, if they are done the way they are supposed to be done.
Why not start of giving charity as a commandment to keep instead of the Sabbath? You guys can decide to become Noahides starting from this moment, and life could be even more exciting and fulfilling.

Comment: The first comment from Harel13 is correct and should be heeded. If your desire is to serve G-d, then you and your family need to focus on following what is taught for you.  When you fulfill your role in service to the Creator of us all, that uplifts all of Creation & places you among the righteous of the non-Jewish nations who have a share in the world to come. In my view, this question is not off topic, nor about comparative religion.

Comment: To put this in context, keeping Shabbat is equated with fulfilling all the commandments. This means that for you it should relate to what you, as a non-Jew have been commanded, your mitzvot which are the 7 commandments of Noah. These 7 are all prohibitions & similarly relate to the prohibitive side of Shabbat, namely that the laws of the Sabbath should not be violated. That includes for you, not to do those things (positive commandments) restricted to the Jewish people.

Answer (score 2):

The 7th day, Sabbath, which began at Creation (Genesis 2:3) has NO instructions for mankind. It merely notes that God sanctified and blessed a specific day.

Did man even know about it? Was man commanded to observe the Sabbath in a prescribed manner? The Bible does not mention anything about Adam, Enoch, or Noah observing the Sabbath.

The first time that we find in Scripture, that man was commanded to observe the Sabbath, was post Exodus (Exodus 16), when God gave the Sabbath as a gift to the Children of Israel (and not to non-Jews).

This was followed at Sinai, where the Sabbath commandment is included in the Decalogue.

> Exodus 31:16-17
>
> 16. Thus shall the CHILDREN OF ISRAEL observe the Sabbath, to make the Sabbath throughout their generations as an everlasting covenant.
> 17. Between Me and the children of Israel, it is forever a sign.

As per Exodus 31, a gentile who observes the Jewish Sabbath [in the manner that God intended it to be kept], is intruding into the private Covenant between God and the Children of Israel, and makes a mockery of the Word of God.